# Unresolved reference for BR.propertyName when calling notifyPropertyChanged, app builds and runs fine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-databinding

I'm using Android Studio 3.5, Kotlin, and databinding.  I have a property setup for 2 way databinding:

```
var startValue: String
    @Bindable get() {
        return when(mode)
        {
            PullingModes.SOTrackingPaintShop->if(salesOrderInformation.zoeordh!!.psstart == null) "" else salesOrderInformation.zoeordh!!.psstart!!
            else->""
        }
    }
    set(value: String) {
       if(mode == PullingModes.SOTrackingPaintShop && salesOrderInformation.zoeordh!!.psstart != value)
           salesOrderInformation.zoeordh.psstart = value


        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.startValue)
    }
```

In the last line, I get a design time error of Unresolved Reference: startValue

The BR class is properly generated, and startValue exists in the generated BR class.  The project builds and runs fine.  I've tried all the common things to try to fix this--clean and rebuild, along with Invalidate caches and restart and still can't get the design time error to go away.  I experience the same issue with the Google sample 2 way databinding project: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-databinding

Anyone else experience this and have a resolution for it?

Comment: Hi! We need more of your code to be able to reproduce your problem. At the very least we need the XML layout file; preferably also the code that inflates it.

Comment: Simply download the official Google example I linked to and look at the TwoWaySample.  I experience the exact same problem with it.  Look anywhere it calls notifyPropertyChanged.  IntervalTimerViewModel is one class to be specific.